# Estimating the variance of Monte Carlo estimators for $F_Z$ and $f_Z$, $Z=X/Y$.

Tags: probability-distributions, monte-carlo

Migrated to [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/425378/estimating-the-variance-of-monte-carlo-estimators-for-f-z-and-f-z-z-x-y).

**Background/Motivation:**

We have $Z=X/Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are independent and $X\sim\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.  The distribution of $Y$ is not important here. We can write the distribution and density functions of $Z$ in terms of expected values w.r.t. $Y$ as
$$
F_Z(z)=\mathsf E\Phi\left(\frac{z|Y|-\operatorname{sign}(Y)\mu}{\sigma}\right)
$$
and
$$
f_Z(z)=\mathsf E\left(\frac{|Y|}{\sigma}\phi\left(\frac{zY-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\right),
$$
where $\Phi(\cdot)$ and $\phi(\cdot)$ represent the standard normal cdf and pdf, respectively.  This leads to unbiased Monte Carlo estimators of the distribution and density functions.  For example, given a sample $Y_1,\dots,Y_n$ we can estimate the distribution function $F_Z$ at the point $z$ via
$$
\hat F_Z(z)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\Phi\left(\frac{z|Y_k|-\operatorname{sign}(Y_k)\mu}{\sigma}\right)
$$
I am interested in evaluating the variance of these estimators as a function of $z$, i.e. $\mathsf{Var}(\hat F_Z)(z)$ and $\mathsf{Var}(\hat f_Z)(z)$.

---

**Approach:**

It turns out in my application $\sigma\ll\mathsf{Var}Y$ so much so that $X$ looks nearly constant in comparison to $Y$. As such, taking limit $\sigma\to 0$ in the above expressions still gives excellent approximations to the cdf/pdf of $Z$. For example, taking the limit $\sigma\to0$ in the expression for the cdf we make use of the fact that the normal cdf tends to a step function giving the approximation
$$
F_Z(z)\approx\mathsf E(\mathbf 1_{z|Y|-\operatorname{sign}(Y)\mu>0}),
$$
and so we have the corresponding MC estimator
$$
\hat F_Z(z)\approx\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\mathbf 1_{z|Y_k|-\operatorname{sign}(Y_k)\mu>0}.
$$
This approximation is very convenient because $\mathbf 1_{z|Y|-\operatorname{sign}(Y)\mu>0}$ is Bernoulli distributed with success probability $p=\mathsf E(\mathbf 1_{z|Y|-\operatorname{sign}(Y)\mu>0})\approx F_Z(z)$, that is we have the distributional approximation $\mathbf 1_{z|Y|-\operatorname{sign}(Y)\mu>0}\sim\operatorname{Binomial}(1,F_Z(z))$. As such we obtain the approximation
$$
\mathsf{Var}(\hat F_Z)(z)\approx\frac{F_Z(z)(1-F_Z(z))}{n}.
$$
This approximations turns out to be very good for my application.  **However, I am unable to see how to extend this idea to estimate $\mathsf{Var}(\hat f_Z)(z)$.** I would think that taking the limit $\sigma\to 0$ of the density would yield something like
$$
f_Z(z)\approx\lim_{\sigma\to 0}\mathsf E\left(|Y|\frac{1}{\sigma}\phi\left(\frac{zY-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\right)=\mathsf E\left(|Y|\delta(zY-\mu)\right).
$$
But it's unclear to me how to proceed from here. Is this last step even correct? Thoughts?

---

**Edit:**

Given $Y$ we note that
$$
|Y|\frac{1}{\sigma}\phi\left(\frac{zY-\mu}{\sigma}\right)
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma/|Y|}\exp\left(-\frac{(zY-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma/|Y|}\exp\left(-\frac{(z-\mu/Y)^2}{2(\sigma/|Y|)^2}\right),
$$
which is a normal density with mean $\mu/Y$ and variance $(\sigma/|Y|)^2$.  So taking the limit $\sigma\to 0$ in the expression for $f_Z$ gives
$$
f_Z(z)\approx \mathsf E(\delta(z-\mu/Y))
$$
So it would seem
$$
\hat f_Z(z)\approx\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\delta(z-\mu/Y_k)
$$
and
$$
\mathsf{Var}(\hat f_Z)(z)\approx\frac{\mathsf{Var}(\delta(z-\mu/Y))}{n}=\frac{\mathsf E\delta^2(z-\mu/Y)-(\mathsf E\delta(z-\mu/Y))^2}{n}\approx \frac{f_Z(z)-f^2_Z(z)}{n}.
$$
This leaves us with
$$
\mathsf{Var}(\hat f_Z)(z)\approx\frac{f_Z(z)(1-f_Z(z))}{n}.
$$
Is this sensible/correct? It's unclear if this result is even guaranteed to be positive.